# Controller.User is Null During Unit Test

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have the following code in my controller action method:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // ...
}
```

It seems to work fine. But when I run a unit test that calls this action, it fails because `User` is null?

Can anyone suggest the best way to deal with this? Do I have to restructure this code just for unit tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to set the User property as part of your setup.  You would do this by mocking the `HttpContextBase` via `ControllerContext` used to create the controller so that it returns your mocked user.  Set your mocked `ControllerContext` into the `ControllerContext` property, and it will find `User` provided you've configured the object graph correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The `User` property of the `Controller` class is copied from the current `HttpContext` - you have to provide a context and set the `User` there appropriately for this to work in your unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

User will be null if you run the code *outside* of the context of a web request. It sounds like you're running tests on your methods directly.

You have two options.

The quickest fix to your problem, but not necessarily the most sustainable fix, would be to simply call your running website from your unit test as a WebRequest.

The more sustainable fix would be to gather your uses of context-dependent server-side functionality (such as `User`) into a single class that you can mock/fake.

**Edit**

> Can anyone suggest the best way to deal with this? Do I have to restructure this code just for unit tests?

The bottom line answer is "yes". More importantly, you probably want to, because it will make your system more flexible and/or maintainable in the long run.