# How do I create Unit Test for Login Action ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core

So the default Login `Action` is:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```

How do I write a unit test `Login_With_Null_UserName_Fails()` that returns `Fail` if the given `LoginViewModel` has a `null` username? I'm completely lost here, any help or tip would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you pls share how do you write the unit test? Did you use .NET 6?

Comment: @Rena oh i think you misunderstood me. See, I want to check if the returned view is Home/Index, I can compare it to my expectedResult(which also is that same view), but in this case it returns `return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl)` which just calls another function and I have no idea what to compare

Comment: Hi, so you mean you not only have not written unit test for the LoginViewModel contains null username but also not written for any other situation? From your code, I never see you return anything if the username is null, or maybe you do not know how to write this also? If you use .Net 6 when the username is null, it will make model validation error, that is why I ask you for asp.net core version.

Comment: I think below link help you : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997530/controller-user-is-null-during-unit-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997530/controller-user-is-null-during-unit-test)